# Javascript form submit preventDefault not working when form is retrieved with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, form-submit, preventdefault

I have a form, which I submit with Javascript and preventDefault. Everything works fine. However, when I retrieve the form with an AJAX call together with other data from a DB, the form will not submit with Javascript anymore, but tries to refresh the entire page with the normal action="" and method="post". It seems that due to the AJAX call, the preventDefault is somehow disabled?

AJAX Call to get form and other data from DB:

```
<a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:loadnames('<?php echo $postid;?>');">Load Names</a>

<div id="form-container"></div>
<!-- is empty, but contains the form upon ajax call above-->
```

The AJAX retrieved HTML Form to submit with Javascript:

```
<div id="form-container">
<!--let user add a name to DB not contained in DB list below-->
<form method="post" action="" id="addnameform">
<input name="name" id="name" type="text" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="add-name-submit" value="Add"/>
</form>
<!--get a list of names from DB-->
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY name ASC";
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
$name = $row["name"];
echo ...
} // end while
?>
</div><!--end-container-->
```

Javascript to submit HTML form above:

```
$("#addnameform").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var $form = $("#addnameform");
var name = $form.find( "input[name='name']" ).val();
$.ajax({
url: "ajax.php",
type: "POST",
...
```

As said, everything works perfectly when the form is displayed on the page upon page load. But as soon as I wrap it inside a container, which at first is "empty", but shows up upon an AJAX call, the preventDefault is somehow disabled.

Comment: You need to use event delegation if the form is created dynamically... `$(document).on('submit', "#addnameform", function(event) {})`

Comment: As the form and therefore the `id="addnameform"` does not actually exist when you run the `$("#addnameform").submit(function(event) {` in I assume a `.ready` handler or similiar. Either do as @ArunPJohny suggests or create the event handler as part of the AJAX `.success`. method after inserting the form into the DOM

Comment: @RiggsFolly, _After inserting form in DOM_

Comment: @RayonDabre Of course, but I suppose to make it clear I should have said that, so I edited the comment. Thanks

Comment: Thanks guys for your help! Took the code from the comment below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to bind the submit event to your body (or any other parent DOM which exists from begining)

```
$("body").on('submit', '#addnameform', function(event) {
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a parent dom object which you load async your form, can you try your jQuery code like below;

```
$(function(){
    $("#form-container").append("<form id=\"addnameform\" method=\"post\"><button type=\"submit\">Submit Me</button></form>");

    $("#form-container").on("submit","#addnameform",function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Submit fired!");
        //Your business goes here...
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/1fta504n/2/

PS: #form-container can be any kind of dom element ex document, "body", "div", ".class" etc

Hope this helps